# Extracting lines from a file if a certain substring is present

Tags: awk

I have a file that looks like:

```
Stef     NY       ID=1;CITY=NY
John     SE       ID=0;CITY=SE
Stef     SE       ID=2;CITY=SE
```

I want to extract only those lines where ID in third column is greater than 1 so the expected output becomes:

```
Stef     SE       ID=2;CITY=SE
```

The bash script I have take care of removing either ID=1 or ID=0 but I don't know how to do it together. This is what I have:

```
awk '$3 !~ /^ID=1;/' file.txt > output.txt
```

But this gives me an output:

```
John     SE       ID=0;CITY=SE
Stef     SE       ID=2;CITY=SE
```

How can I add ID=0 in my bash statement above? Insights will be appreciated.

Comment: `[01]` matches either `0` or `1`. Thus, `'$3 !~ /^ID=[01];/'` removes either.

Comment: Will you always have single digit `ID`? Can it be: `Stef     NY       ID=01;CITY=NY` also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> awk '$3 !~ /^ID=1;/' file.txt > output.txt

### How it works

Your AWK command (anything between the quotes) works like a filter.

- `$3 !~ //` filters by a condition on the 3rd field (`$3`). The condition is a **not matching** (`!~`) regular expression (between the slashes `//`).

`^ID=1;` is a regular expression matching all lines **starting with (`^`)** `ID=1`.

### Adjust the regex

As [Charles Duffy commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69256618/extracting-lines-from-a-file-if-a-certain-substring-is-present#comment122409548_69256618) you could simply  change the constant literal pattern `ID=1` for a more flexible one like either of those:

- `ID=[01];` the ID can be any char inside **character-set** (the set inside square brackets `[]`), so either 0 or 1
- similar set defined as range: `ID=[0-1];` (from 0 to 1)
- or even distinct alternatives `ID=(0|1);` whereas alternatives are listed in a group (wrapped inside parentheses) separated by a pipe symbol (`|` often meaning logical-OR)

All above will match 2 cases.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit fragile, but you could try:

```
$ cat input
Stef     NY       ID=1;CITY=NY
John     SE       ID=0;CITY=SE
Stef     SE       ID=2;CITY=SE
$ awk '$2>1' FS='[=;]' input
Stef     SE       ID=2;CITY=SE
```

That is, split the line on the `=` and `;` so that the number you're looking to compare is in field 2.

Comment: why is it fragile?

Comment: It's fragile because it will fail if any of the names contain `=` or `;`, or if the 3rd columns changes order and looks like `CITY=SE;ID=5`, or any number of other reasons.

Answer (score 2):

The expression is a regular expression so you can use:

```
awk '$3 !~ /^ID=[01];/' file.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do numerical comparison by stripping out all unwanted characters from last field:

```sh
awk '{val=$NF; gsub(/(^|.*;)ID=|;.*/, "", val)} val+0 > 1' file

Stef     SE       ID=2;CITY=SE
```

This will also work correctly for input like this:

```
Stef     NY       ID=1;CITY=NY
Stef     NY       ID=01;CITY=NY
John     SE       ID=0;CITY=SE
Stef     SE       ID=2;CITY=SE
Stef     SE       ID=04;CITY=SE
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility with `awk` could be:

```
awk '$NF ~ /^ID=[[:digit:]]+/ {split($NF,a,/=|;/);if (a[1]=="ID" && a[2] > 1) print $0}' file
Stef     SE       ID=2;CITY=SE
```

- Initial condition: only if last field  begins by the sequence
  of characteres of the regexp `/^ID=[[:digit:]]+/`
- action: split the field with the separator `=` or `;` and then check the condition `(a[1]=="ID" && a[2] > 1)` If true, print the current line.